# Are modern browsers good at scaling images down nowadays?

Tags: image, browser

Back in the old days, one would always need to scale images in Photoshop, because the browsers did a terrible job of it. Firefox now seems to scale images smaller quite nicely. Do the other browsers do a nice job too?

Comment: You don't just scale down because the browsers weren't good at it (yes they're all better now) you also scale down because of bandwidth - why make them download 40,000 pixels (200x200) when they can only see 250 (50x50)?  This effects their speed to see the image and your bandwidth and hosting costs.

Comment: Of course, I believe in serving images at the correct size. But I'm building a contact management system where each contact is allowed one avatar image, and I may need to display slightly different sizes dending on the context. But your point is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer 7 doesn't do so well, but IE8 does. You can change IE7 to use the better method from IE8 with a simple line of CSS.

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```

P.S. I found this out when working on an intranet page where bandwidth wasn't a problem. For something on the internet I would seriously consider resizing the image to reduce the number of bytes.

Comment: I'm trying this on IE10 and it doesn't seem to yield any improvement when scaling down. "Interpolation" suggests that it is used for scaling *up* rather than down, no?

Comment: @tennenrishin, interpolation is used any time you need to create a point in between existing points. This will be the case whether you're scaling up or down. The example I spoke of was definitely scaling down.

Comment: Suppose I want to display a 300x300 pixel image in a 30x30 pixel space. Each displayed pixel covers the area of 100 pixels in the original image. How is bicubic interpolation (which derives each pixel from only 4 neighboring pixels and their derivatives) going to help (unless the image's frequency-band happens to be extremely restricted)?

Comment: @tennenrishin, there's nothing in the definition of the word "interpolation" that requires it to only sample 4 pixels. It's possible to stretch out the bicubic formula and apply it to more pixels. That said I don't know anything about the details of IE's implementation.

Comment: As you said, "interpolation is used any time you need to create a point between existing points". Now, if the "point between" happens to fall exactly on one of the "existing points", then it would take on the value of that existing point, would you agree?

Comment: Suppose we have a 1001x1001 image of a white wall, with a tiny black ant precisely in the center of it. The whole image is white, except the very center pixel, which is black. If we downsample this image to a 3x3 image using only interpolation, then we will get an image that is 11% black! It doesn't matter what kind of interpolation was used, because our center pixel (if considered to be a point) falls exactly on the original image's center pixel. A pixel covering the area of many of the original pixels is not "a *point between* existing points", but an *area covering* existing points.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether or not you're safe to display large images in small areas on a webpage, I wouldn't risk it:  resize the image prior to posting/let your framework resize the image.  You'll save the client from downloading a huge file, and you'll know exactly how the image will display.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers are good at scaling images, although none will be as good as a proper graphics application.

However if you have a graphic you are scaling to be smaller it still has to be downloaded before scaling it, so it is better to have a small one if you can, especially if you have mobile clients